# How to force an explicit animation to occur in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I created this View modifier which animates a change in the offset of a view based on a boolean Binding and resets itself when the animation finishes (also resetting the boolean Binding).

```
struct OffsetViewModifier: AnimatableModifier {
    let amount: Double  // amount of offset
    @Binding var animate: Bool  // determines if the animation should begin
    
    private(set) var pct = 0.0  // percentage of the animation complete
    
    var animatableData: Double {
        get { animate ? 1.0 : 0.0 }
        set { pct = newValue }
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .offset(x: amount * pct)
            .onChange(of: pct) { newValue in
                if newValue == 1.0 {  // If newValue is 1.0 that means animation is complete
                    withAnimation(.none) { animate = false }  // When animation completes, reset binding
                    // Since I don't want this to cause an animation, I wrap it with withAnimation(.none)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I used this new modifier like this:

```
VStack {
    Text(tapped.description)
    Circle()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .onTapGesture {
            tapped = true
        }
        .modifier(OffsetViewModifier(amount: 50, animate: $tapped))
        .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 3), value: tapped)
}
```

However, the `withAnimation(.none)` didn't work, and this view still takes 3 seconds to reset.

How do I force the explicit animation to occur and not the `.linear(duration: 3)` one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood this correctly, what you should do is wrap `tapped` within `withAnimation` because the `.animation` is modifying the whole view like this.
tapped is binded to animate, when you change animate's value in the modifier, you're changing the value of tapped, therefore, executing the linear animation

```
VStack {
    Text(tapped.description)
    Circle()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 3)) {
                tapped = true
            }
        }
        .modifier(OffsetViewModifier(amount: 50, animate: $tapped))
}
```

My personal advice is to avoid using .animation() because like I said before it will animate the entire view and will cause problems like this one